# Auto save performance for rdbms

Tags: performance, scalability

In my app user types in some content which I would like to auto save as the user types. The save call is not for every keystroke, rather I do autosave only when user pauses for more than 200ms. So in a typical paragraph there are 15-20 server calls. The content will not be read very often, so I need to optimize the writes.

I have to save data on MSSQL Server because of legacy code reasons. I'm getting 10 seconds avg response time in my load test. How do I improve the performance?

One approach I'm considering is instead of directly saving data in mssql I'll save it in Cassandra or redis, then eventually(maybe at regular time intervals) write it to mssql.

Another approach is instead of doing frequent updates, I'll insert new record for each auto save. Then a background process will clean up all records except for latest, every few minutes.

Update:
I replaced the existing logic with simple update calls to 2 tables and now I am seeing improvements. There was a long stored procedure which was taking upto 10 seconds under load. SO for now I have hold on the problem. Still I would like to know is there something I can do on application server layer to reduce frequent DB calls.

Comment: Where or why is it taking 10 seconds? Can you show the query, table structure index etc? Or are you meaning end to end takes 10sec? I also use autosave and see overall times in mS.

Comment: @rlb See my update. a long stored proc was taking 10 seconds under load. I changed it to simple update statements and I can see improvements. I'll provide further updates after I run load test. Do you hit db in every autosave call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite hard to answer yor question directly but here are some hints based on what we do in a multiple active user situation.

If you are writing/triggering on every keystroke, pass the keystroke to a background thread and do not perform the database write, or any network call, while blocking the users typing. A fast typist can hit 20 keystrokes/second, and you cannot afford to introduce latency.

If recording on a web page, you might be able to use localStorage. Do not issue an AJAX style call on every keystroke as there is a limit to outstanding requests.  You need to implement some kind of buffered send. Remember that network calls in the real world can be 300mS sort of scale just to traverse the network.

Do you really need to save every keystroke, or is every N seconds acceptable? Every save operation will eventually turn into a disk operation, so you really want to coalesce as many saves as possible. The quickest way to do something is not to do it at all.

If you are recording to a database, then it is often quicker to update an existing row, if you can fetch it by direct key first. Unfortunatly it can sometimes be quicker to insert a new row and clean up excess later. This tends to be true if the table has few indexes. Which is quicker depends on database engine in use and how it is being used. We use both methods.

When using a database keep in mind that they often keep journals of some kind, so if you are updating frequently you might create a large load on the journal files.

If you are using techniques (Using C terminology) like fopen, fwrite these can perform very well, but if you are worried about system failure recovery, you may need to call fsync, which then limits your maximum performance rate. If you need fsync, a database might be better.

You might like to consider writing to a transactionlog table very frequently, and then posting to the real storage every N seconds. For example, if I am typing a customers name I might record every keystroke into a keylog table, and then have a background job read the keylog table and transfer the data to customers table.  This helps reduce the operations to the customers table while also allowing the keylog table to be optimised to recording keystrokes.  But, at the cost of more code server side.

Overall, you want logic like this

On keyup handler

1. Add keystroke to background queue
2. Wake background thread

Background thread

1. Read/remove ALL data from background queue
2. If no data, wait for wakeup and repeat
3. Write to database/network/file etc as one operation. (this can now be syncronous calls)
4. Optionally some velocity control, simple one is sleep(50mS) or sleep(2s)
5. Repeat

Keep in mind with the above the user can type and immediately hit close, so your final buffer write might not have flushed yet. You need to handle this.

If you get this correct, the user will not notice any delay.  In our usage, we are recording around 1000 keystrokes/sec average, all of which ar routed over private networks to central points.  This load is barely a blip, even network monitoring does not see such a small amount of traffic.
Good luck.

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed answer. I don't save on every keystroke, rather I send autosave call when user stops typing for more than 300ms. So in a paragraph of text the call will go 10-20 times. 
I had thought of a background thread approach, but my concern is if I'm storing state on an app server, I won't be able to scale horizontally.